# Secure Erase of a Bash Environmental Variable

Tags: linux, bash, security, scripting, cryptography

Suppose I have in a Bash shell script an environmental variable that holds a sensitive value (e.g. a password). How may I securely overwrite the memory that holds this variable's value before exiting my script?

If possible, the technique used to do so would not be dependent on the particular implementation of Bash I'm using. I'd like to find a standards-respecting/canonical way to do this that works on all correct Bash implementations.

Please note that the following are not in the scope of the question:
1. How the sensitive value is placed into the environmental variable
2. How the sensitive value stored in the environmental variable is passed to the program that consumes it

**7/10/2017 5:03 AM Update to Address Comment by rici**

rici, thank you for your comment, copied here:

> "Exiting the script is really the only way to reliably delete an
>   environment variable from the script's resident memory. Why do you
>   feel the string is less safe after the script terminates than while it
>   is running?"

My intent here is to follow good practice and actively scrub all cryptographically-sensitive values from memory as soon as I am through using them.

I do not know if Bash actively scrubs the memory used by a script when that script exits. I suspect that it does not. If it indeed does not, the sensitive cryptographic value will remain resident in memory and is subject to capture by an adversary.

In C/C++, one can easily scrub a value's memory location. I am trying to find out of this is possible in Bash. It may be that Bash is simply not the right tool for security-sensitive applications.

Comment: I'm going to guess that there is no "standards-respecting" way to do this, as there's likely no way to do so period (other than potential hacks).  If you're really worried about this, the most expedient way to solve this would be to run a dedicated Bash process, and then terminate once you're done with the password.

Comment: Yeah, I'm worried that there may not be. I don't know if there are standards that define what a "correct" Bash implementation is and, if there are, whether or not they address the particular issue I'm looking at here.

Comment: well, presumably you only need to worry about [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), because anything else isn't Bash ;)

Comment: Exiting the script is really the only way to reliably delete an environment variable from the script's resident memory. Why do you feel the string is less safe after the script terminates than while it is running?

Comment: rici, I have updated my original post to address your comment. Thank you for your response?

Comment: "In C/C++, one can easily scrub a value's memory location." This is not true at all. Ensuring that memory is securely cleared is extremely difficult in C and even more so in C++ (when using tools outside of C like vector or string). Just writing `memset(key, 0, size)` doesn't ensure that the data at `key` is actually gone. Optimizing compilers are tricky beasts, and modern memory management is quite complicated and does not always do quite what you think it's going to do. It may *appear* to do what you were expecting, but it may not actually be implemented the way you assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, we need to distinguish between [*environment* variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) and *shell* variables. Environment variables exist for the lifetime of the process and cannot be overwritten. Not only that, but on many systems they are trivially visible to other processes. For example Linux provides the [`/proc` filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) which allows for lots of introspection of running processes, including observing their environment variables.

Here's an example of a Bash script that attempts to overwrite an environment variable. Notice that although the value *within* the script changes, the process' environment is not changed:

```
$ SECRET=mysecret bash -c \
  'strings /proc/$$/environ | grep SECRET
   SECRET=overwritten
   echo "SECRET=$SECRET"
   strings /proc/$$/environ | grep SECRET'
SECRET=mysecret
SECRET=overwritten
SECRET=mysecret
```

So it is never safe to store secrets in environment variables unless you control all access to the machine.

Holding a secret in a (non-environment) shell variable is much more secure, as an attacker would need to be able to access the memory of the process, which is generally something only the kernel can do. And while you're correct that minimizing the time you hold onto such secrets is a good practice, it's not generally worth jumping through lots of hoops for. It's *far* more important to secure your system and execution environment, because a motivated attacker who has sufficient access can observe a secret even if it only lives in memory for a brief time. Holding a secret in memory for longer than strictly necessary is only a marginal increase in risk, whereas running a privileged program on an insecure system already means all bets are off.